# Determine the differences between 2 objects

Tags: java, algorithm, object, comparison

I'm working something similar to an audit log, which requires logging the fields that are different between 2 given objects.

For example, I have these 2 objects, `oldFoo` and `newFoo` of class Foo. Let's say this class has more than 20 fields. I wanted to know what fields are different - what are the fields in `newFoo` that were previously `null` in `oldFoo` but no loner are? What are the fields in `newFoo` whose values were changed or set to `null`.

Of course, I can always do it the dumb way like this:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>> diff (Foo oldFoo, Foo newFoo)
{
   Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>> ret = new HashMap<String, List<Map<String, Object>>();
  List<Map<String, Object>> added = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
  List<Map<String, Object>> changed = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
  List<Map<String, Object>> removed = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

  if (newFoo.getField1() != null && oldFoo.getField1() == null)
  {
     added.add(new HashMap<String, Object>().put("fieldName", "field1")
                                            .put("oldValue", "")
                                            .put("newValue", newFoo.getField1());
  }
  else if (newFoo.getField1() == null && oldFoo.getField1() != null)
  {
     removed.add(new HashMap<String, Object>().put("fieldName", "field1")
                                              .put("oldValue", oldFoo.getField1())
                                              .put("newValue", "");
  }
  else if (newFoo.getField1() != null && oldFoo.getField1() != null && !newFoo.getField1().equals(oldFoo.getField1())
  {
     changed.add(new HashMap<String, Object>().put("fieldName", "field1")
                                              .put("oldValue", oldFoo.getField1())
                                              .put("newValue", newFoo.getField1());

  }  

  //keep going for *MORE THAN 20* fields... :(
  //...

  ret.put("CHANGED", changed);
  ret.put("ADDED", added);
  ret.put("REMOVED", removed);
  return ret;

}
```

But I'm sure there has to be a smart way out there.
Any suggestion?

*** Update 1 ***
I'm trying to avoid using reflection as much as I possibly can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use reflection to do the whole thing generically.

Just scan through every field in the object using reflection and build up a list of every field that has a different value.

That code would then work with any two objects you like!

Incidentally I'd create a `Change` class with `fieldName`, `oldValue`, `newValue` fields rather than abusing hash maps for that. The class will be much clearer/more readable, run faster, use less memory, etc.

Without reflection you have very few options. You might be able to do something with annotations (scan for annotations rather than for member variables). The other option would be to change the class to be a `HashMap` and not have member variables at all.

Comment: Ah, I should've mentioned I'm trying NOT to use reflection.

Comment: You really have to use reflection for accessing components of classes in this way. It is **the** built-in way to do this.

Comment: Then you pretty much out of luck. Reflection, maybe annotations, and ditching your class for a HashMap are pretty much your only options here. This is exactly the sort of thing reflection was built for though so I don't know why you wouldn't use it...

Comment: Yeah I was considering some change class instead of `HashMap`, but still, don't like the idea of reflection unless that's the only way, which seems to be... :(
The `HashMap` option to change the main class to not have any member at all wouldn't work for me, unfortunately.

Comment: There's nothing scary about Reflection. If you're doing this sort of thing, you'll have to play with it sometime ;-)

Comment: Not that it's scary, I'm just worried about the performance and reflection never seems neat to me.